# One of my friends messaged me on Xbox Live, and he's offline

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I was just playing a game when on of my friends messaged me about playing a game. My friend was marked as offline. If didn't say when he was last online. my friend was never online. it simply was marked offline. is there an explanation for a user messaging me and he's offline?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to enable it, but it is possible to be logged in to Xbox Live and appear offline. This will hide your current activity from anyone on your friends list. Since you are connected to Xbox Live, this lets you do anything that requires Xbox Live as usual (playing multiplayer, sending messages, etc.).

Comment: On the 360, you pull up the guide, go to the far right tab, go to preferences, and there's a way to appear 'away', 'busy', or even offline.